# Why does the website gets "This site has requested that you identify yourself with a certificate" popup?

Tags: ssl, certificate, iis, private-key

Recently I added a SSL certificate I received to a newly migrated website. Since no issues can be identified on most of the machines , some users complained of getting a 403 forbidden error. When these users loads the site they are getting a pop up with the following message `"This site has requested that you identify yourself with a certificate"`, which requires them to select a certificate. If they cancel it they can view the website without any issue but if they select a certificated form the drop-down on the popup they are redirected to a 403 error. The website is hosted on IIS.
Is this an issue with the certificate? how can i resolve it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The server certificate is fine, but you accidentally enabled *client* certificate verification in IIS. (Client certificates in TLS work like SSH user keys.)

According to this screenshot I found on Google, you probably selected both "Require" options in the SSL Settings page – but the "Client certificates" mode should have been set to "Ignore" instead.

[image: Screenshot of IIS Manager "SSL Settings" page]